Why does this function require a lifetime when all the arguments implement the copy trait?
In the following code, I don't understand why the Span require a lifetime.
Since all the arguments implement the copy trait, my understanding is that the Span own all the required variables.
use ratatui::{
    style::{Color, Style},
    text::Span,
};

/// Take a u8, and render a colorized ascii, or placeholdler
fn render_ascii_char(val: u8) -> Span {
    match val {

        val if val > 0x20 && val < 0x7f => {
            Span::styled(
                val.to_string(),
                Style::default().fg(Color::LightCyan)
            )
        },

        _ => {
            Span::styled(
                "•",
                Style::default().fg(Color::Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}

fn test_function() -> Span {
    let val = 0x42;

    render_ascii_char(val)
}

fn main() {
    let _my_span = test_function();
}

This code use ratatui. Bellow the Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "span_lifetime"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2024"

[dependencies]
crossterm = "0.27.0"
ratatui = "0.26.2"

I have the following error message when compiling with cargo build:
$ cargo build
   Compiling span_lifetime v0.1.0 (/tmp/playground/span_lifetime)
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:7:34
  |
7 | fn render_ascii_char(val: u8) -> Span {
  |                                  ^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime, but this is uncommon unless you're returning a borrowed value from a `const` or a `static`, or if you will only have owned values
  |
7 | fn render_ascii_char(val: u8) -> Span<'static> {
  |                                      +++++++++

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:26:23
   |
26 | fn test_function() -> Span {
   |                       ^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime, but this is uncommon unless you're returning a borrowed value from a `const` or a `static`, or if you will only have owned values
   |
26 | fn test_function() -> Span<'static> {
   |                           +++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0106`.
error: could not compile `span_lifetime` (bin "span_lifetime") due to 2 previous errors

Using a <'static> lifetime doesn't seems like a good idea, since I don't use this function only with constants.
Using a reference val: &u8 as an argument, instead of val: u8 does work.
But it create issues when the value passed goes out of scope.
My solution so far is to specify a lifetime:
fn render_ascii_char<'a>(val: u8) -> Span<'a> {
    match val {
[...]

But I don't really understand why this is required, nor the implications of this lifetime.

From the definition of Span:
pub struct Span<'a> {
    pub content: Cow<'a, str>,
    pub style: Style,
}

You can see it contains a Cow which might contain a reference in the Borrowed variant:
pub enum Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}

and because of that the struct itself needs to be annotated with a lifetime as you can't add a lifetime dynamically (that's inherently impossible because types and lifetimes are a compile time construct only!).
Since you don't fulfill any of the conditions in which the lifetime can be elided, you have to explicitly add it.
'static is the correct lifetime to use here, it doesn't at all mean you do or can only use the returned Span with constants, but instead that it doesn't contain any references that live shorter than 'static.

My understanding is that using 'static make the variable live for the duration of the running program (https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#reference-lifetime).
As this function is used a lot in my code, it seems using 'static would cause some kind of memory leak where I always allocate memory that is never freed. Or am I misunderstanding something here ?

Okay, my understanding is that using 'static means we are pointing to some memory that is always valid. Either a constant (here our '•') or an owned value.
Since val is copied when passed to the function, this is an owned value. So 'static is the correct course of action.
I would love if someone can confirm this

'static doesn't have any effect whatsoever for the Cow::Owned (String) variant here. It's only used in Cow::Borrowed in which case yes, the pointed to memory has to live for the rest of the program, but that's trivially true for string literals like "•", they are compiled into the executable. A lifetime annotation (not even 'static) by itself can not possibly create a memory leak, only an explicit method like Box::leak can. This is however a common lifetime misconception
